# In what circumstances is sufficient a sequence of i.i.d RV with finite EV and finite, positive Variance of the Lyapunov-Condition?

Tags: probability-theory

In what circumstances is sufficient a sequence of i.i.d RV with finite Expected value and finite, positive Variance of the Lyapunov-Condition?

Where Lyapunov-Condition is given by: 
Let $\delta > 0$

$L_n(\delta)=\dfrac{1}{Var(S_n)^{(2+\delta)/2}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}(\left | X_k-\mathbb{E}X_k) \right |^{2+\delta}) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

It is sufficient to suppose that sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ follows standard normal distribution with EV=0 and variance=1?